# Specific website is not opening on LAN

Tags: ethernet, internet

I have very specific problem, one of our company website is not opening on any browser, but I am able to open that in other computer.

What exactly the issue is, I am using following IP Address

```
192.168.100.88
255.255.255.0
192.168.100.1

DNS 8.8.8.8
Pref DNS is blank
```

When I use this IP, the specific website is not opening, but when I go to the LAN setting and make the IP settings automatic, then the website is opening perfectly.

Can anybody please suggest whats the issue with using the IP address above?

I thought there is a conflict with other computers so I changing multiple IPs but no luck.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question precisely we would need to know the web site address and the result of DNS resolution test toward this name (using nslookup on Windows or dig on Linux / Mac OS)

This may due to a split DNS scheme.

**This scenario could explain your issue:**

- Let's say the web site is `www.mycompany.com` and the public IP address of this website is `198.51.100.17`
- In the internal network the IP address of the server is a private one, for example `172.16.0.8`
- There's a NAT rule that will translate traffic destined to `198.51.100.17` port 80 (HTTP) or 443 (HTTPS) to `172.16.0.8`

**This is the setup, now what's happening?**

When inside the network you will use your internal DNS resolver, and when resolving `www.mycompany.com` the DNS server will respond `172.16.0.8`. This address is of reachable and everything is fine.

Now, when you manually set your DNS server to google one, `8.8.8.8`, and you ask for `www.mycompany.com`, you will get `198.51.100.17` and not `172.16.0.8`

So your browser will try to reach the **external** IP address of your company router from the **internal** interface. Since the NAT rule apply only to traffic coming on the external interface, this fail.

When you set your computer to DHCP (I suppose this is what you mean by "make the IP settings automatic"), then you receive the correct, I.E. internal, DNS server address and it works as intended.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried with entering the IP which was generated while checking in command and entered the same, I was using the gateway which was incorrect.

Comment: You should not use the IP address to access web sites. Many web sites use the URL to provide the correct web site and will not respond (correctly) when accessed by the IP address. (look up for "virtual host" or "host header" for more info)